# AS3 Flash app reading online XML doesn't update. Possibly Cache related

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, caching

I have a small as3 Flash that uses several online XML files. These XML files fill up several textfields in my flash, so that way I can update the contents just by changing the XML files. This flash also has a "edit" option to edit the file and save a XML file on the server on top of the old one.

Now the thing is that the flash suposedly would open up the new files and come up with the updated textfields, but only the olds ones appear.

I can confirm that in the server they are updated (just dowloaded them and see that they have the updated fields), but whenever my flash loads them, it always load the old ones, which make me assume there is some "download cache" that I have to clean. I also confirmed with traces that flash is download the right files.

Also, I tried restarting the PC and deleting the browser cache to see if it was something temporary, and it did nothing.

So, is there a way to clean the "online download cache", or am I looking at the wrong problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution to my problem here: http://willperone.net/Code/as3nocache.php .

Basically, like the article sugests, I changed my URLRequest to something like:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("whateverurl?nocache=" + new Date().getTime());
```